# RabbitMQ - subscribe to multiple queues

Tags: rabbitmq, scheduling

I have a system of producers and workers. The producers produce tasks. I need to distribute the tasks to the workers. The tasks have types. The workers are specialized. Each worker can handle a subset of task types. For instance, I have tasks types: A, B, C, D

```
Worker1 can handle tasks types { A, B, C }
Worker2 can handle: { A, C }
Worker3 can handle: { A, B, D }
etc...
```

Not all the workers run all the time. So it would be even possible that for some task type there won't be a running worker which is able to handle the task so the task would have to wait in a queue until the worker which is capable to handle the task starts.

The system should be fair, so the tasks should be handled in the same order (if possible) as they come.

It seems I would need to create a queue for the each task type and subscribe the worker to that types which they are capable to handle.

However, it seem it is not possible to blocking subscribe to multiple queues. The only way how to implement this is active waiting.

Any ideas? Is RabbitQM appropriate for this problem?

Comment: All your requirements seems to be available in RabbitMQ. Consider reading their easy to understand tutorial [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html)

Comment: I would need something like: QueueSet([q1, q2, q3]).subscribe(...).

Comment: If there is facility for receivers/clients to subscribe to one queue then a wrapper can be written in order to subscribe to multiple queues. But yes, you will need to write your own classes if you really want to work with abstraction w.r.t subscribing to queues and receiving the messages. For eg in PHP, in order to receive a message from a particular queue the code is: `$channel->basic_consume('hello', '', false, true, false, false, $callback)`. In order to receive messages from multiple queues  you will need to declare multiple queues or handle all messages depending upon ID in same callback.